# Xbox Labelled Apps on Windows 8.1 App store

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

Many games in the Windows app store are labelled Xbox. Do they work on 8.1 Windows PC ?

Comment: Why not try one or more out?

Comment: @Karan I don't have much bandwidth. All those apps are like 1.6 GB or more. Downloading them is costly at this time for me.

Comment: The Store clearly lists whether the apps are for x86, x64 or ARM. What other information do you need?

Comment: @Karan I have x86 PC.  So, the app will work but labelling it XBox means would it work with XBox connected ? Please don't downvote. x86 is generic the listings are too broad, you didn't get the question.

Comment: I got your question all right. Read up regarding XBox accounts, achievements and other relevant details. If you feel the listings are too broad and you are interested in a specific game, read some reviews to figure out how it works on PCs. BTW I haven't bothered to downvote yet, so kindly don't tempt me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xbox is branding that gets applied to games/music/video across Microsoft platforms. When you're looking at the store from your Windows 8.1 device, it shows the install button for stuff you can actually install.  So, if it shows an install button on a Windows 8.1 PC, it works on some Windows 8.1 PC.  I say "some" because there are other reasons it might not work.  Like its too demanding for your rig, for example.